# Only return entries within the last hour

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, delta

I'm trying to filter data in my csv file to show only  entries with time between current hour and 1 hour prior.

Data looks as follows after filtering only the columns for `CreatedAt` and `ID`:

```
                CreatedAt        ID
2021-11-26 09:36:05-08:00     99702
2021-11-26 07:21:36-08:00    645478
2021-11-25 09:34:00-08:00    204446
2021-11-25 00:19:08-08:00    394719
2021-11-24 23:08:15-08:00    769537
                              ...  
2016-01-22 12:16:28-08:00    278137
2016-01-22 10:55:31-08:00    374485
2016-01-22 09:55:22-08:00    807451
2016-01-21 12:23:36-08:00    346137
1969-12-31 16:00:01-08:00    883029
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col='CreatedAt', parse_dates=['CreatedAt'])
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["CreatedAt"], ascending=False)
end_time= datetime.datetime.utcnow()
last_hour= end_time - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
filtered_dates = sorted_df.loc[last_hour]

print (filtered_dates)
```

When I print `filtered_dates`, the code is correctly calculating the delta between the 2 times, but for some reason it's not printing the entirety of the data I'd like to see.

Any assistance is always appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col='CreatedAt', parse_dates=['CreatedAt'])
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["CreatedAt"], ascending=False)
end_time= datetime.datetime.utcnow()
last_hour= end_time - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
filtered_dates = sorted_df.set_index('CreatedAt').between_time(last_hour, end_time)
```

or

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col='CreatedAt', parse_dates=['CreatedAt'])
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["CreatedAt"], ascending=False)
end_time= datetime.datetime.utcnow()
last_hour= end_time - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
time_window_mask = sorted_df["CreatedAt"].between(last_hour, end_time)
filtered_dates = sorted_df[time_window_mask]
```

Comment: I'm getting this with what you shared: 

raise TypeError("Index must be DatetimeIndex")
TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex

Comment: Have edited my proposal

Comment: I'd suggest you use pd.Timestamp instead of Python datetime (especially not utcnow ! )